# Visual studio 2015 bring back exception window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For a few days my exception window looks like the following.

[image]

The previous window (that is gone for unknown reason) allowed me to go through inner exception etc, but this is next to useless. No amount of options tinkering helped me get old window back.

Adding more information, this is the code I am using in two projects - one, my main project, second, a new console application I just created for this test.

On my main program I have added line:

```
throw new Exception("test");
```

On my new console application I only have this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new Exception("Why is my Exception Window Working Here");
    }
}
```

The resulting exception windows are as follows:
On my main app:
[image]

On new console app:

[image]

What I want to do, is to bring back the same exception window as I have inside new console application.

Comment: What is the inner exception? Where does it happens? What file, class, method, line?

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference - no matter where and what kind of exception happens I get this window, which is totally different from one I had before, and I have no idea how to bring it back.

Comment: It is impossible to help without more data (`MissingArgumentException: the method 'VisualStudio2015BringBackExceptionWindow 'needs arguments be provided to be called in file 'StackOverflow' for class 'Questions' at line 67517476`).

Comment: Alrightie, added all the info I could, I know this is tricky problem to solve, given this little info, but I've been struggling with it for quite a bit already.

Comment: It does not help more. I see nothing about System.Data.Entity. I don't understand the problem: if you throw en exception, thus you will get this VS behavior, or a crash box if runned from the shell... Thus again: what is the problem you want to solve and what is the real code that causes it? What file, what class or struct, in what method or property and at what line. If you go to the doctor and tell I have pain without telling where and how, what to do?

Comment: The problem is - my visual studio exception window changed and became useless and I have no idea how to fix it. This is not a code-driven problem, but more of a tool problem.
Going by your analogy, I showed you how my broken arm looked before (the image from bare console project), and now I show you how it looks now, and I have no idea how to fix it, hoping someone here will :)

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use the new Exception Helper".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN